# In TypeScript, what does <T> mean?

Tags: typescript

Consider:

```
export declare function createEntityAdapter<T>(options?: {
    selectId?: IdSelector<T>;
    sortComparer?: false | Comparer<T>;
}): EntityAdapter<T>;
```

What does the <T> mean?  I know `<>` is a type assertion, but I don't know what `'T'` is. What is this function is doing?

Comment: Also this article could be helpful: 
https://rossbulat.medium.com/typescript-generics-explained-15c6493b510f

Answer (score 253, accepted):

> What does the `<T>` mean?

That is TypeScript's [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) declaration.

Excerpt:

> A major part of software engineering is building components that not only have well-defined and consistent APIs, but are also reusable. Components that are capable of working on the data of today as well as the data of tomorrow will give you the most flexible capabilities for building up large software systems.
>
> In languages like C# and Java, one of the main tools in the toolbox for creating reusable components is generics, that is, being able to create a component that can work over a variety of types rather than a single one. This allows users to consume these components and use their own types.

You mentioned:

> I don't know what 'T' is.

`'T'` is going to be a type declared at run-time instead of *compile* time.  The `T` variable could be any non-declared variable (I couldn't find a reference, but I would assume any valid set of characters that could be used for a variable names).  Similarly in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), if the type `T` represents is not a value type but a more complex type (class) or interface, it could be named/declared as `TVehicle` or `TAnimal` to help denote a valid type for future programmers (and could be considered best practice because just `T` is not intuitive). I prefer `TSomething` because I know that uppercase T means a generic type.  `WSometing` or `ASomething` is also valid, but I just don't prefer it.  (Microsoft's APIs are almost always [TContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506(v=vs.113).aspx) or [TEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx) for example).

> It'd also be helpful if someone could explain to me what this function is doing.

Well, the function isn't *doing* anything.  This is more declaring a type of function that can have multiple run-time type values.  Instead of explaining that, I'll include an excerpt taken directly from the link above.

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}
```

which can be used like:

```
// type of output will be 'string'
let output = identity<string>("myString");
```

or

```
// type of output will be 'string', the compiler will figure out `T`
// based on the value passed in
let output = identity("myString");
```

or

```
// type of output will be 'number'
let output = identity(8675309);
```

Which might beg the question:

> Why use generics

JavaScript has arrays, but when you retrieve a value from the array, it literally could be anything (TypeScript: `any`).  With typescript you get Type safety by declaring them like:

```
 // Array<T>
 let list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
 // or
 let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

Now each value in the array has a type.  TypeScript will throw a compile-time error if you attempt to put a string into this array.  And you get type safety and intellisense (depending on your editor) when you retrieve a value:

```
class Person {
  FirstName: string;
}

let people: Array<Person> = [];
people.push({ FirstName: "John" } as Person);

let john = people.pop();
// john is of type Person, the TypeScript compiler knows this
// because we've declared the people variable as an array of Person

console.log(john.FirstName);
```

Declaring type'd generic constraints. A very good example of [Open - Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

> In object-oriented programming, the open/closed principle states "software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification";[1] that is, such an entity can allow its behaviour to be extended without modifying its source code.

In the following example, anyone could extend Human or Cheetah or even create their own derived type and the Logger functionality would continue to work without any modification.

```
interface IAnimal {
  LegCount: number;
}

class Cheetah
  implements IAnimal {
  LegCount: number = 4;
}

class Human
  implements IAnimal {
  LegCount: number = 2;
}

public class Logger<TAnimal extends IAnimal> {
  public Log(animal: TAnimal) {
    console.log(animal.LegCount);
  }
}

var logger = new Logger();
var human = new Human();
logger.Log(human);
```

[Working Example](https://codepen.io/erikphilips/pen/LJYQda?editors=0022)

In the previous example I used a [Generic Constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to limit the `TAnimal` type programmers can use to create a `Logger` instance to types that derive from the interface `IAnimal`.  This allows the compiler to asssume that the value type passed to the `Logger` class always has a property `LegCount`.

> You can explain to me why in the TypeScript documentation they put <T> instead of putting something more descriptive like <Identity> for example. Nothing and <T> for me is the same. Now does everyone use the <T> like fools, or did I miss something?

*These are all going to be assumptions in the following.  I do not know neither the team who designed the TypeScript generic system nor the team who wrote the documentation.*

At the root level of generics is the ability to use `T` as *any possible type* (not to be confused with TypeScript's `any`).  Meaning `Array<T>` is the *interface* (for lack of a better word) and when we create a concrete type we replace `T` with a declared type:

```
Array<number>
```

So for the *interface* `Array<T>` what makes more sense than `T`?  I don't know.  I do know that `T` has to be a Type (number, string, etc) so it makes sense to use `T` because it the first letter of the word *Type*.  I think `Array<Type>` would be really confusing and/or might even be invalid if *type* or *Type* became reserved or restricted (currently `type` has special meaning in certain contexts so it's also a poor choice) so avoiding those is a good choice.  Other languages ([C-sharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)) also choose to use `T`, so switching between languages and being able to use the same term is advantageous.

On the flip side what would the following mean?

```
Array<Identity>
```

What is `Identity` here?  There is no constraint to help other developers or future developers know what it is.  It would appear to me to be a specific typed Array that I must implement explicitly, which means it's not up to me to choose the generic type.

```
interface Foo1 {
  bars: Array<Identity>;
}
```

In the previous example, I (and probably most developers) would assume that Identity is an existing type and I cannot change it.

```
interface Foo2<T> {
  bars: Array<T>;
}
```

With `Foo2` I know I have to choose a type.

```
interface Foo3<Identity> {
  bars: Array<Identity>;
}
```

`Foo3` is just confusing.

```
interface Foo4<TIdentity> {
  bars: Array<TIdentity>;
}
```

Now with `Foo4`, I am much more confident that I must choose the type, but I'm still a bit confused why `TIdentity`.  Obviously in some contexts, where the type is more defined, it would make sense.

As of March 2021, the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) has been updated to deprecate the use of `<T>` in documentation, in favor instead of `<Type>`.

That being the case, I *personally* find the following confusing and would highly suggest avoiding `Type` it for two reasons.

```
interface Lengthwise {
  length: number;
}

function loggingIdentity<Type extends Lengthwise>(arg: Type): Type {
  console.log(arg.length);
  return arg;
}
```

The first reason to avoid naming your type `Type` when using constraints is that it doesn't read very well within the method nor with multiple methods.  Imagine the logging methods are much longer than 2 lines, and all of a sudden all you're reading is the word `Type` everywhere.

```
interface Lengthwise {
  length: number;
}

interface Widthwise {
  width: number;
}

function loggingLength<Type extends Lengthwise>(arg: Type): Type {
  console.log(arg.length);
  return arg;
}

function loggingWidth<Type extends Widthwise >(arg: Type): Type {
  console.log(arg.width);
  return arg;
}
```

I think the following is much more readable:

```
interface Lengthwise {
  length: number;
}

interface Widthwise {
  width: number;
}

function loggingLength<TLengthwise extends Lengthwise>(arg: TLengthwise): TLengthwise {
  console.log(arg.length);
  return arg;
}

function loggingWidth<TWidthwise extends Widthwise>(arg: TWidthwise ): TWidthwise {
  console.log(arg.width);
  return arg;
}
```

Secondly it's very possible to have more then 1 generic and that makes the following invalid (hopefully for obvious reasons).

```
interface Lengthwise {
  length: number;
}

interface Widthwise {
  width: number;
}

function loggingLength<Type extends Lengthwise, Type extends Widthwise>
(arg1: Type, arg2: Type) {
  console.log(arg1.length);
  console.log(arg2.width);
}
```

While the documentation uses `Type` for showing off simplistic and mundane examples, I highly suggest not using `Type` in any real world code.

Comment: Phillips I have also seen <R> and <U>. What do these mean or can I use any character inside the angled brackets?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson Updated answer, thanks that will be helpful for future readers, great question.

Comment: Thanks @ErikPhilips, You can explain to me why in the Typescript documentation they put `<T>` instead of putting something more descriptive like `<Identity>` for example. Nothing and `<T>` for me is the same. Now does everyone use the  `<T>`  like fools, or did I miss something?

Comment: @jcarlosweb Updated my answer, I hope it can answer your question.

Comment: "'T' is going to be a type declared at run-time instead of compile time." <-- what does this mean? Typescript don't have run time

Comment: @AcidCoder it's the best description I can come up with, without getting all technical about the all the explicit details.  For example, `s: string` is compiled as a string.  `s: T` isn't compiled at all, only it's runtime versions of `s: <whatever generic T was defined as>`.  But to your point at runtime, there is actually no type-system at runtime (technically they are both compile only).

Comment: So, basically `T` is just a label, it can be replaced by any letter or word, and it doesn't have to be capitalized either. In the industry `T` become a default "generic" label, just like `foo` as variable name and `bar` as its value.

Answer (score 21):

It is noteworthy to mention that as of March 2021, the TypeScript documentation has been updated to deprecate the use of `<T>` in documentation, in favor instead of `<Type>`. [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Comment: While the use of `Type` is in the documentation, I have added worth reasons *not to use it*.

Comment: Indeed, I find it interesting that Microsoft chose to make `Type` the standard.

Answer (score 17):

The example you provide is a function with a generic parameter.
`T` (which does not have to be `T`. You could call it `G`.) is called a generic template where actual type of the `T` is replaced at runtime.

Imagine EntityAdapter has following implementation:

```
interface EntityAdapter<T> {
   save(entity: T);
}
```

Below code returns an EntityAdapter which content is `any`. `any` could be number,string, object or anything.

```
let adapter1 = createEntityAdapter<any>(<parameters here>)
```

Below code returns an EntityAdapter which content is `Car`.

```
let adapter2 = createEntityAdapter<Car>(<parameters here>)
```

Basically `Car` is more specific than `any` so that you can get extra type safety. So how does this help?

In a nutshell, generic template can give you extra type safety. For example,

```
adapter1.save('I am string') // this works because `T` is `any`
adapter1.save(new Car()) // this also works because `T` is `any`

adapter2.save('I am string') // this wont works  because `T` is `Car`, typescript compiler will complains
adapter2.save(new Car()) //this works because `T` is `Car`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like the way you explained that T could be any character or set of characters. I have often see <R> & <U> and wondered if they had special meaning. I gues that means 'no'?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson Yep you are right. They do not have any special meaning as far as typescript concerns.

Comment: To make it clear and if I am understanding this right, T is just a placeholder for later type uses. Is that correct?

Answer (score 9):

It is called Generics, helps we write safe yet flexible functions.It provide variables to types. In short, you can create a function, interface or class that works with different types, without specifying the type up front.
Below some demo code to explain why we use it and how to use it.

```html
// any is too general ,and it loses the meaning of using typescript

function insertAtBegining(array:any[],value:any) {
    let newArr = [value, ...array];
    return newArr;
}

// if we specify the type number , this function will lost it's utility 

function insertAtBegining(array:number[],value:number) {
    let newArr = [value, ...array];
    return newArr;
}

// if we specify the type string , this function will lost it's utility 

function insertAtBegining(array:string[],value:string) {
    let newArr = [value, ...array];
    return newArr;
}

const demoArr = [1, 2, 3];

const updatedArr = insertAtBegining(demoArr, 4);
// more generic functions

function insertAtBegining<T>(array:T[],value:T) {
    let newArr = [value, ...array];
    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: why do we need <t> after insertAtBegining? Can't we just have 
`function insertAtBegining(array:T[],value:T) {
    let newArr = [value, ...array];
    return newArr;
}`

Comment: @SamKahChiin in that way T would be undefined