# Should Typescript generics be used to force an interface when calling a method?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to wrap my head around generics and wondering if I'm applying it correctly here.

Consider the following:

```
interface NameValuePair {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}

function flatten(data: NameValuePair[]) {
    return data.reduce((obj, pair: NameValuePair) => {
        obj[pair.name] = pair.value;
        return obj;
    }, {});
}

const formData: NameValuePair[] = [
    { name: "firstName", value: "John" },
    { name: "lastName", value: "Doe" }
];

let flattened = flatten(formData);  
// { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }
```

Whenever the function is called, I'd like Typescript to enforce the usage of a custom interface that describes the final data structure. For example, using `formData` from above, a possible interface could look like:

```
interface ProfileForm {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

The following is my attempt at using generics:

```
function flatten<T>(formData: NameValuePair[]): T {
    return <T>formData.reduce((obj: T, pair: NameValuePair) => {
        obj[pair.name] = pair.value;
        return obj;
    }, {});
}

let flattened = flatten<ProfileForm>(formData);
let firstName = flattened.firstName;
let age = flattened.age; // typescript error
```

It works as expected, but, through testing, it appears to provide the same results as:

```
function flatten(formData: NameValuePair[]) {
    return formData.reduce((obj, pair: NameValuePair) => {
        obj[pair.name] = pair.value;
        return obj;
    }, {});
}

let flattened = <ProfileForm>flatten(formData);
let firstName = flattened.firstName;
let age = flattened.age; // typescript error
```

In this particular case, do generics provide any benefit?

Comment: I am writing the answer, but can you tell what is your real intention? What are you trying to solve with TypeScript? Why do you want to have such interfaces?

Comment: The main idea is to force anyone who uses the flatten() function to provide an interface to map the return value to. Specifically, flatten() is for converting a form into a JSON object. Each form is different, with different fields. I figured, since Typescript is a typed-language, this kind of enforcement is what the language was written for. Am I taking the idea of type-enforcement too far?

Comment: Ok. Did you try the solution in my answer though?

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
const formDataRaw: NameValuePair[] = [{ name: "fullName", value: "John Doe" }]

// please note that reduce() was unnecessary, or you used it wrong. 
// Anyway, your question should be focused, TypeScript and reduce() is 
// two unrelated things, especially in your code I didn't see how they 
// were related

const formData: NameValuePair = formDataRaw[0]

interface NameValuePair {
    name: keyof ProfileForm | keyof OtherForm;
    value: string;
}

interface ProfileForm {
    fullName: string;
}

interface OtherForm {
    otherProp: string;
}

type ResultingForm<NVP extends NameValuePair> =
    NVP['name'] extends keyof ProfileForm ? ProfileForm :
    NVP['name'] extends keyof OtherForm ? OtherForm :
    never

interface Flatten {
    <NVP extends NameValuePair>(formData: NVP): ResultingForm<NVP>
}

const flatten: Flatten = <NVP extends NameValuePair>(obj: NVP) => {
    return { [obj['name']]: obj['value'] } as unknown as ResultingForm<NVP>
}

flatten(formData) // <--ok
flatten({ name: 'fullName', value: 'zxc' }) // <--ok. Code Completion works
flatten({ name: 'otherProp', value: 'zxc' }) // <--ok. Code Completion works
flatten({ name: 'foo', value: 'zxc' }) // <-- error
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this produces the result I'm looking for. Specifically, `flatten()` is supposed to take an array of objects, not a single object. I reworked my original question to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> The following is my attempt at using generics:

```
function flatten<T>(formData: NameValuePair[]): T {
  return <T>formData.reduce((obj: T, pair: NameValuePair) => {
    obj[pair.name] = pair.value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
}
```

Well you are using generics, but in *way* in which you're using it has no benefit.  The goal with any programming language should be to use the least about of code to provide the desired result.  In this instance, a non-generic method with the following signature does the same thing without generics:

```
function flatten(formData: NameValuePair[]): ProfileForm {
  return formData.reduce((obj: T, pair: NameValuePair) => {
    obj[pair.name] = pair.value;
    return obj;
  }, {}) as ProfileForm;
}
```

I suppose one could use the generic way to provide different results with the same input, but then really it should just be an interface at that point.

So in this case don't use generics.  Which then you might ask [What exactly does Generics provide and why should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622045/in-typescript-what-does-t-mean/49622066#49622066).

Comment: If `ProfileForm` was the only possible interface, using it for the return type makes sense, but there could be any number of interfaces. For example, `interface LoginForm { username: string; password: string; }` or `interface SettingsForms { timezone: string; }`. In that case, would it make sense to have `flatten()`s return typehint be an empty interface and then each specific interface extends that? E.g.`interface Form {}` and `interface ProfileForm extends Form { ... }`?

Comment: Based on your comment, you are trying to roll up code into something that does multiple things, which kinda breaks the Single Responsibilty Principle.  You should have a method that pull the properties needed for each type.