# What does <value> or <values> in typescript mean?

Tags: typescript

What does values mean below? I've also seen value. Couldn't find anything referring to value as a type in the docs.

```
type something<Values> = {
   ...
}
```

```
export type SomeAPI<Value> = {
  input: someInputProps<Value>
  helpers: someHelperProps<Value>
  messages: {
    error?: string
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript what does <T> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622045/in-typescript-what-does-t-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values is a generic in this case. Equivalent to

```
type something<T>
```

you use generics as a sort of placeholder for a type that you define when you use your type, for instance like:

```
type Items<T> = { items: T[] }
```

you've defined a type `Items` that has a property `items` which is an array of generic type `T` that can then be used like:

```
interface MyType { id: number }
const myTypeItems: Items<MyType> = { items: [ {id:1} ] };
```

by doing this, you've used a generic to restrict a property to contain an array of a certain type.

Comment: so it's the same as any?

Comment: no, not the same as any, updated answer to include a brief explanation of generics. but any means it can be any type, a generic means it's a placeholder for a type yet to be specified.

Comment: Thanks for this! can you explain in my 2nd example how the values of an object can have the same type as the object? I'm just not sure what the purpose of doing something like that is

Comment: I don't see why I couldn't have just replaced `<Value>` with `object`

Comment: Because object isn’t a generic. It’s an actual type. It might be treated like a generic in this case but you shouldn’t use reserved types in a generic declaration. People usually use things like T or TValue to denote that this is generic and you need to provide the actual type when you use it. If one of my junior devs declared a generic as Value I’d reject the PR personally. Like i said, generic doesn’t mean the same as any or object. Any or object are actual types that basically mean this can be almost anything. A generic means you haven’t told me the type yet and will need to later.

Comment: It’s important to use a generic in your second example because you’re restricting both the subproperties to use the same type. If they were both any or object there would be no restriction.