# What does `Array<class>` mean in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is some code that I came across. Why does it say `dogs: Array<Dog>` and not `dogs: Array[Dog]`? Thank you.

```js
class Dog {
  public name: string // leaving out 'public' would work too
}

class PetStore {
  dogs: Array<Dog>

  printAllDogNames(): void
  {
    this.dogs.forEach(dog => {
      console.log(dog.name);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622045/in-typescript-what-does-t-mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript what does <T> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622045/in-typescript-what-does-t-mean)

Answer (score 1):

It is a generic array, you can read in this link:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Array

TypeScript, like JavaScript, allows you to work with arrays of values. Array types can be written in one of two ways. In the first, you use the type of the elements followed by [] to denote an array of that element type:

```
let list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```

The second way uses a generic array type, Array:

```
let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```