# What does <T = {}> mean?

Tags: typescript

I found this generic type in the docs:
`type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

There's only a short comment above that line saying this is a Generic Constraint. But it isn't described in the docs for Generic Constraints:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints

So how does <T = {}> work? What constraints does it enforce?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript what does <T> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622045/in-typescript-what-does-t-mean)

Comment: It doesn't enforce any constraints. It's an optional generic type parameter with the default value of {} if not specified

Comment: No Christián. `<T = {}>` is not the same as `<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints); those use `extends` to enforce that the generic type parameter is assignable to some other type:

```
// the type T must be assignable to {a: string}
type Foo<T extends { a: string }> = T;

type A = Foo<{ a: "hello" }> // {a: "hello"}
type B = Foo<Date> // error!
```

Instead, it's a [generic parameter *default*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), which is a fallback type that the compiler uses if you do not specify or the compiler cannot infer the type parameter:

```
// the type T will be {a: string, b: number} if you fail to specify it:
type Bar<T = { a: string, b: number }> = T;
type C = Bar<Date> // Date
type D = Bar // {a: string, b: number}
```

They are independent, but you can use the both together to constrain a type parameter and provide a default (which must be assignable to the constraint itself):

```
// both
type Baz<T extends { a: string } = { a: string, b: number }> = T;
type E = Baz<{ a: "hello" }> // {a: "hello"}
type F = Baz<Date> // error!
type G = Baz // {a: string, b: number}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsFMITwA6wCqgLYFcDO5QCNYBDLLASwHMA7QvAG1nAHtQBvQgLlBwCdTLyAvgFgAUOESwAYo0YAeVNAAe4aJQAmWVqA5dwvfqAEA+UAF5QyANyjR4pKACCZ0NLkttnAEQxatRp8MTEFYdb2hff2ExCVAAIWdXWQARQhUgsGhubkZuAEIbEWCoBhjUAHdSX3xYNk4ePnIAGnxOSgw0Am4BUFIAM1A4RgxQXsJKiGYsJABjPrge8HZbGNjCbnlndx16-ma8VvbOwOcrZfsAYWdV9ZS00GDb6DPYJKu1+7Ba3X0mltA2jqZKKiYJ4RhQZ5xQgALw2ShU6k0Wzqegahk2Hm+DT2B0B3GO5lO0XsAFE3rDkaAwhEAsYPiEvD4-J4onYpOTkqloOlQJlsnlIQBxcn0r47X77f6HIFAA)